# TYPO3: login form on page + sub pages

Tags: authentication, typo3

In TYPO3, how do I get a login form to be the first rendered content element on a page and all its sub pages? I tried to check the "recursive" option but that doesn't seem to do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to set up something like this. Here's one approach:

1. Add a separate content section in your backend layout right above the current section.
2. Use [slide](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html#slide) to have pages inherit content for this section from their parent pages
3. Put the login form in that section on your the root page of your subtree.

This rather simple approach leaves control to the editor.

The *recursive* option you mentioned is very likely related to the record storage page and tells TYPO3 to look for records (here: users) in subpages of the selected page.

Comment: how do I add a content section? when I search for the keywords, the resulting links do not even contain the word section. not sure which concept you are referring to?

Comment: I can only point you to blog articles in German like [TYPO3 Backend Layouts über Page TSConfig in Dateien auslagern](https://www.braune-digital.com/blog/typo3-backend-layouts-ueber-page-tsconfig-in-dateien-auslagern/) but the code snippets should give you an idea.